# Difference between php and libapache2-mod-php

Tags: php, apache

When running php as a module inside apache we intall it on ubuntu for example using the command:
sudo apt-get install -y php libapache2-mod-php

So the question is what is the difference between the two packages? isn't the libapache2-mod-php module enough?

Comment: `php` is likely the CLI package, and the other is an apache module.